# HTML scrset attribute loading wrong image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, srcset

I am having an issue with loading the correct responsive image using scrset.

I am using the following sizes attribute:

```
sizes="(max-width: 767px) 95vw, 768px"
```

and the following scrset attrivute:

```
srcset="https://cdn.runningshoesguru.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Nike-Pegaus-35-Turbo-photo-9.jpg 1280w, https://cdn.runningshoesguru.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Nike-Pegaus-35-Turbo-photo-9-300x225.jpg 300w, https://cdn.runningshoesguru.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Nike-Pegaus-35-Turbo-photo-9-768x575.jpg 768w, https://cdn.runningshoesguru.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Nike-Pegaus-35-Turbo-photo-9-633x474.jpg 633w"
```

so I would expect the 768px version to load on desktop but instead the full size version is always loaded.

You can see the full html/css in action here:

https://output.jsbin.com/nelikarewu

Am i doing something wrong?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line `sizes="(max-width: 767px) 95vw, 768px"` to `sizes="(max-width: 767px) 95px, 768px"`

Comment: That's not what i am trying  to do... on mobile devices the image should take 95% of the viewport and on desktop be fixed to 768px

Comment: Do you want the image size always be of 768px in desktop no matter what size has the window and only in mobile take 95% of the container size?

Comment: yes correct.. the problem is that the full size image is loaded on desktop and not the 768px one